# Inserting data into postgresql json columns using clojure.java.jdbc

Tags: json, postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I'm trying to do an insert into a json column in a postgresql database using `clojure.java.jdbc/insert!`.  I'm not sure which data format should be used when inserting json.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE errors (
    id character varying(24) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    body json NOT NULL
);
```

Trying to use literal data in a map format:

```
=> (insert! db :errors {:id "a" :body {:message "A error"}}
                       {:id "b" :body {:message "B error"}})
PSQLException No hstore extension installed.  org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setMap (AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1709)
```

Alternatively as a json encoded string:

```
=> (insert! db :errors {:id "a" :body "{\"message\":\"A error\"}"}
                       {:id "b" :body "{\"message\":\"B error\"}"})
PSQLException ERROR: column "body" is of type json but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 46  org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse (QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
```

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do this.  Of particular importance is that I need to be able to insert many records in a single query instead of one by one, a convenience `insert!` is providing for me.

What is a simple way to insert several records into a postgres table having a json column using clojure.java.jdbc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since clojure.java.jdbc exposes a few protocols, including `clojure.java.jdbc/ISQLValue`, you can extend it to allow supplying json as an ordinary clojure map.  Travis Vachon provides [a thorough explanation of this process](https://web.archive.org/web/20161024231548/http://hiim.tv/clojure/2014/05/15/clojure-postgres-json/) and a code snippet implementing it.

I also found a library, [clj-postgresql](https://github.com/remodoy/clj-postgresql), which implements lots of extra postgres functionality, including json and jsonb data types.  You can simply require `clj-postgresql.types` and json support will be imported.

Comment: The link to the "thorough explanation of this process" is dead! Do you have an alternative source?

Comment: @rdgd Replaced it with an internet archive link.